# How to generate Tree structure JSON

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

Data Structure **User -> ManagerId (User)**

Hierarchy

User 1 -> User 2 -> User 3 -> ……

User 1 -> User 2A-> User 3A -> ……

**Correct JSON format**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "User 1", 
        "children": [
            {
                "Name": "User 2", 
                "children": [
                    {
                        "Name": "User 3", 
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "Name": "User 4", 
                                "children": [], 
                                "RecordId": "0050w000003mHhHAAU", 
                                "Parent": "0050w000003m3xuAAA"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "RecordId": "0050w000003mHhHAAU", 
                        "Parent": "0050w000003m3xuAAA"
                    }
                ], 
                "RecordId": "0050w000003mHhHAAU", 
                "Parent": "0050w000003m3xuAAA"
            }
        ], 
        "RecordId": "0050w000003kdW8AAI", 
        "Parent": "0050w000003mHhHAAU"
    }
]
```

This is My Code(**only get to the next level**)

```
List<TreeTable> returnList = new List<TreeTable>();
List<User> userList = [
    SELECT ID,Name,ManagerId 
    FROM User WHERE ID IN ('0050w000003kdW8','0050w000003mHhH','0050w000003m3xu')
];

Map<Id,List<TreeTable>> userTreeMap = new Map<Id,List<TreeTable>>();
for (User userinfo : userList) {
    
    if (userinfo.ManagerId == null) {
        continue;
    }

    if (userTreeMap.containsKey(userinfo.ManagerId)) {
        TreeTable tt = new TreeTable();
        tt.RecordId = userinfo.Id;
        tt.Name = userinfo.Name;
        tt.Parent = userinfo.ManagerId;
        userTreeMap.get(userinfo.ManagerId).add(tt);
    }else{
        TreeTable tt = new TreeTable();
        tt.RecordId = userinfo.Id;
        tt.Name = userinfo.Name;
        tt.Parent = userinfo.ManagerId;
        userTreeMap.put(userinfo.ManagerId, new List<TreeTable>{tt});
    }
}

for (User userinfo : userList) {
    TreeTable tt = new TreeTable();
    tt.RecordId = userinfo.Id;
    tt.Name = userinfo.Name;
    tt.Parent = userinfo.ManagerId;
    if (userTreeMap.containsKey(userinfo.Id)) {
        tt.children = userTreeMap.get(userinfo.Id);
    }
    returnList.add(tt);
}

System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'returnList = ' + JSON.serialize(returnList));

public class TreeTable {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id RecordId;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Name;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Parent;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<TreeTable> children;
}
```

I've tried very hard to generate, but encountered `Query 101`. Is there a better way to generate correct JSON in one query?

Comment: There's no reason for a 101 error here, the problem would be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching on my part, I found a solution, hope it helps someone else.
[source code](https://live.playg.app/play/dynamic-tree-structure-with-lwc)

```
public with sharing class DynamicTreeStructure {
    public DynamicTreeStructure() {}

    private static Map<Id, TreeStructure> result;
    private static Map<Id, Id> childIdMap;

    /**
    Static Method to be fed in @wire for LWC
    */
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<TreeStructure> getDatas(){
        result = new Map<Id, TreeStructure>();
        childIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
        Map<Id, Folder_Management__c> folderMap = new Map<Id, Folder_Management__c>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Folder_Management__c WHERE ParentId__c = null]);
        if(!folderMap.isEmpty()){
            startFetchingAccountDetails(folderMap);
        }
        
        return result.values();
    }

    /**
    * Recursion method to get all levels of accounts and their related records
    */
    private static List<TreeStructure> startFetchingAccountDetails(Map<Id, Folder_Management__c> folderMap){
        Map<Id, TreeStructure> parentStructure = gatherAllAccountInformation(folderMap);

        //attach the first level to actual result and rest will auotmatically link
        //due to pass by reference way
        if(result == null || result.isEmpty()){
            result.putAll(parentStructure);
        }
        Map<Id, Folder_Management__c> childMap = new Map<Id, Folder_Management__c>([SELECT Id, Name, ParentId__c FROM Folder_Management__c WHERE ParentId__c =: folderMap.keySet()]);
        if(childMap != null && !childMap.isEmpty() && childMap.size() > 0){
            Map<Id, Id> accChildIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
            for(Id childAccountId : childMap.keySet()){
                Folder_Management__c child = childMap.get(childAccountId);
                childIdMap.put(child.Id, child.ParentId__c);
            }

            //run this method recursively to get all child levels.
            List<TreeStructure> childStructure = startFetchingAccountDetails(childMap);
            for(TreeStructure child : childStructure){
                TreeStructure parent = parentStructure.get(childIdMap.get(child.name));
                parent.items.add(child);
            }
        }
        return parentStructure.values();
    }

    /**
    * Method to gather all information for all accounts recieved
    */
    private static Map<Id, TreeStructure> gatherAllAccountInformation( Map<Id, Folder_Management__c> folderMap){
        Map<Id, TreeStructure> result = new Map<Id, TreeStructure>();
        for(Id recordId : folderMap.keySet()){
            Folder_Management__c acc = folderMap.get(recordId);
            TreeStructure accStructure = new TreeStructure(acc.name, recordId, true, null);
            result.put(recordId, accStructure);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public class TreeStructure{
        @AuraEnabled public String label;
        @AuraEnabled public String name;
        @AuraEnabled public Boolean expanded;
        @AuraEnabled public List<TreeStructure> items;
        public TreeStructure(String label, String name, Boolean expanded, List<TreeStructure> items){
            this.label = label;
            this.name = name;
            this.expanded = expanded;
            if(items != null && items.size() > 0){
                this.items = items;
            }else{
                this.items = new List<TreeStructure>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```